# PHP losing data inside the object after unserialize

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

I am storing an USER object inside a session by serialize first, than I am trying to use it on the same page to test it however it doesn't retrieve the data that was initialize everything is blank.

```
$user = new User();
echo '<br/>' . $user->getUsername(); // Gives me corerct data
userSession(serialize($user)); // Stored into session

$userObj = unserialize($_SESSION['userObj']); // Still get an object of type User
echo $userObj->getUsername(); // This returns blank unlike the first call
```

If anyone can assist me it will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**userSession Code**

```
function userSession($userObj){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userObj'] = $userObj;
}
```

**USER CLASS**

```
class User{
    protected $pdo;
    private $id, $username, $banned, $email, $first_name, $last_name, $mobile_phone, $city, $address, $postal_code, $user_type, $active;
// Create a user
    public function __construct(){
        $con = new Connection();
        try{
             $this->pdo = $con->getConnection();
        }catch (PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage(); // Store to file
        }
    }
```

Comment: is you `session_start()` always before any call to your user object ?

Comment: Can you show the code for `userSession()` - that's a big missing step that could have an effect.

Comment: Show the code for the serialize/unserialize methods

Comment: @WaldsonPatricio `serialize()` is a native PHP function.

Comment: I have added the userSession function

Comment: add the User class, there could be something happening in there causing your problem.

Comment: Serializing class objects can be tricky, not sure if this helps: http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.serialization.php

Comment: added the User Class as well

Comment: @1nflktd public inside my User Class! Like this : public function getUsername(){return $this->username;}

Comment: @1nflktd I didn't the issue was there (didn't want to clutter the question with lot of code). Since it works before i serialize but not after

Comment: Does anybody know if it could be b/c the properties are private? I also don't see where the query results are saved to the individual properties.

Comment: @mopo922 nope just tried that too! :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing the full `User` class, try serializing just the data and using the same data to create a new object after.
Basically, what you'd do is add a `User->getData()` and `User->setData()` where one would return all the data that is relevant in a format you can save (JSON, serializable Array) and the other would allow you to create a new `User` object and load this data back in.